# Show failed function instead of macro in gtest

Tags: c++, console, macros, wrapper, googletest

currently I'm working on creating new tests using gtest. There are some cases where I use same groups of EXPECT_EQs, so I wrap them up in a function. And now when particular test failes, it prints out the line where EXPECT that failed was written instead of the line where wrapper function was called.

```
class TestSuite : public ::testing::Test
{
public:
    void wrapperForExpects(const std::string& str)
    {
        EXPECT_EQ(0, 0);
        EXPECT_EQ("zero", str);
    }
};

TEST_F(TestSuite, exampleName)
{
    std::string exampleVariable = "one";
    wrapperForExpects(exampleVariable);
}
```

In this example line number 7 will be printed out as failed to console, but I would like to see line number 14. How can I do that?

Comment: https://google.github.io/googletest/advanced.html#using-assertions-in-sub-routines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done by adding `SCOPED_TRACE("exampleName")` before the function call. This will create something similar to the stack trace in the output:

```cpp
TEST_F(TestSuite, exampleName)
{
    SCOPED_TRACE("exampleName_scope");  // <------ Add this
    std::string exampleVariable = "one";
    wrapperForExpects(exampleVariable);
}
```

Live example: https://godbolt.org/z/nnzvjGc8P

See [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JJqRlSTQlh4&t=3596s) for more examples.